# Authenticate Users on Excel using Power Automate API to retrive Data

Tags: excel, authentication, power-automate, azure-entra-id

I'm trying to connect Excel to an API in Power Automate, it works fine without any login form, but when I select "Any user in my tenant" the login options on excel don't work.
[Screenshot of power automate "When a HTTP request is received" flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACMTE.png)

I need to authenticate the user calling the API and check if the email address is enabled to view the data from the API but i'm stuck on login / authentication problem, it works fine from Postman with Entra ID setup to log the users.